# How to Get The Parameters Name From The Http request

Tags: java, servlets

I want To Get The Parameters Name From My Http request, Please Give me the Solution, Thanks In advance

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use.

```
  Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();

        while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {

            String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement();
            out.write(paramName);

        }
```

You can visit following link for more details.
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/servlet/get-all-request-parameters-in-servlet/

Comment: Ya Praveen,But I Dont KNow The Parameters Name ,I Just Want to Get All The Parameters From My Jsp PAge.